# Facebook Marketing API How to fetch Custom audience match Rate

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am using Facebook Marketing API java SDK to create a custom audience list.I am passing a list of 1000 email/phone numbers to create custom audience list.I can get the audience list id in response. Is there any way to fetch the match rate in the list(How many audience have actually matched with a facebook user - some of the users may not have a facebook profile)

[Facebook marketing API doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way.

You can retrieve the Custom Audiences with their approximate counts like this:

```
ArrayList<CustomAudience> audiences = adAccount.getCustomAudiences()
       .requestField("approximate_count")
       .execute();
```

You can also suppy a list of parameters to `requestFields` function to retrieve more than one field. Like this:

```
ArrayList<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
fields.add("name");
fields.add("approximate_count");
fields.add("delivery_status");

ArrayList<CustomAudience> audiences = adAccount.getCustomAudiences()
     .requestFields(fields)
     .execute();
```

Or you can query one Custom Audience `approximate_count` field from it.

To see all the available fields for Custom Audiences see [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience) from Facebook.